# definition of purely atomic random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I can't seem to find the relevant definition for this.

Let $X_k$ be a sequence of independent RV's with $N$ being an rv.

define $\mu(A) = \sum_{k=1}^N 1_{\{X_k \in A\}}$.

I am trying to prove hat $\mu(A)$ is purely atomic.

The problem is, I can't find the definition of purely atomic for random variables. From the definition of $\mu$ above, we see that it's a random variable. I'm not asking how to prove this but I'm just asking what I need to show. (This is a hw)

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory)